# How to access Rails's 'can't be blank' error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

What's the API to access Rails's default `can't be blank` error message when validation `:presence => true` fails?

I have the model setup like this:

```
class TextDocument < Document
  validate :content_not_blank   # 'content' is an attribute

  private
    def content_not_blank
      if content.blank? 
        errors.add(:content, ....?) # I want to access 'can't be blank'
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`I18n.t('errors.messages.blank')`

should give you what you want.

Comment: how do we translate this default messages. I mean there are many default messages, and I want to create for ex ru.yml for them

Answer (score 24):

Assuming you're using standard yaml translations, you can find the file in [ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml)

To override it you'd drop a file in your `config/locales` folder, e.g.:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "can't be whatever your custom message"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it with the default method like this:

```
validates_presence_of(:content)
```

This will generate the right message (can't be blank) in the current local (if you setup your config/locales/ ..yml files

if you really want to write your own validator

```
errors.add(:content, I18n.translate(:blank))
```